# Convert System.String array into php string array

Tags: c#, php, .net, web-services, symfony

I have a client developed in C# which sends data via web services on my website (developed with Symfony).
I try to send a `System.String` array, but when I recover it in PHP, it contains an index-value format like the following:

```
[0]      S
[1]      y
[2]      s
[3]      t
[4]      e
[5]      m
[6]      .
[7]      S
[8]      t
[9]      r
[10]     i
[11]     n
[12]     g
```

So, how can I send my data to recover my data without problems in PHP ?

Comment: show some code please

Comment: Not sure what you get back exactly. Are you sure PHP checks for UTF-16 strings?

Comment: UTF-16 ? but why ?
I don't need to show some code, I just want the theory ... and it's complex to show some code in this case ...

Answer (score 0):

Isn't "implode" what you're looking for in php?

Something like [this](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.implode.php)?

And to use it :

```
$string = implode("",$yourArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is :
 - In .NET I have an array of string :

```
[0]      array0
[1]      array1
[2]      array2
[3]      array3
[...]
```

When I send it to PHP, I am obtaining that :

```
[0]      S
[1]      y
[2]      s
[3]      t
[4]      e
[5]      m
[6]      .
[7]      S
[8]      t
[9]      r
[10]     i
[11]     n
[12]     g
```